# DoScheduledTelemetryRun runs repeatedly

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, office365

Using Win 7 Home.

I have a rundll32 task with the parameter: DoScheduledTelemetryRun which has been running for days using 50% of the CPU. appraiser.dll is also on the command line.

I have an Office 365 ProPlus subscription - I opted out of the "experience" program in the middle of troubleshooting this problem but it still keeps coming back after reboots. Office 2007 is installed as well - can't find the setting for the experience program but I never sign up for those on purpose.

I had a recent subscription change but I had the same change on another Win 7 PC w/o this problem.

Anyone recognize this problem and what to do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appraiser.dll is part of Windows and not office. Use ProcessExplorer/Taskmanager to kill this rundll32.exe process.

It looks like Update [KB2952664](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952664) [triggered that run](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2911609/operating-systems/kb-2952664-compatibility-update-for-win7-triggers-unexpected-daily-telemetry-run-may-be-snooping.html). Looks like Microsoft wants to check which software users have installed to test them, if they prevent the upgrade to Windows 10.

Run Task Scheduler (type task scheduler in the find box of start menu), then on the left move down to Task Scheduler Library->Microsoft->Windows-> Application Experience, select the generated task, do a right click and click on disable.

Comment: Appears to be a case of very bad manners on the part of Microsoft combined with cases where the accesser.dll runs for an excessive amount of time and CPU consumption. There doesn't appear to be a way to defeat the tool - we have all opt'ed in to have our computers scanned somewhere in the fine print. Stopping the process didn't work, it just restarts until satisfied. Kill the task didn't work as it just gets re-added by some other process.

Comment: I installed some optional updates which may have cleaned up the troublesome KB - they didn't say that of course - but my problem went away. It may be that it was finally done after several days of scanning. My guess is it got distracted by Flight Sim(s) which has quite a few GB of additional scenery

Comment: I have an idea -- someone should calculate/publish the carbon footprint of this program disabling low power state over millions of computer world wide! I'm sure there are models on savings due to being able to drop into low power CPU and disk ops - these are being defeated by this program.